Как в "Visual Studio Community 2022" добавить новый шаблон в "Добавить новый элемент..."?
Не могу никак найти информацию об этом, все статьи ссылают на то, что необходимо в пункте меню "Проект" нажать кнопку "Экспорт шаблона...". Но у меня её нету.

Попытался вручную создать ".vstemplate" файл, поместил вместе с файлом шаблона в папку "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ItemTemplates". Чуда не произошло.
Содержимое файла ".vstemplate":
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Qt Widgets UI</Name>
    <Description>Описание вашего шаблона</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <DefaultName>Qt Widgets UI</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">interface.ui</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>

Может фигню полную делаю, подскажите кто знает как сделать столь нечто простое.

CSharp... Естественно у вас ничего не появится, измените на cpp или как там должно быть...

Так в том и дело, что я не знаю как должно быть. Мне бы рабочий пример, чтобы я по примеру сделал.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/template-tags?view=vs-2022#built-in-tags я же вам сказал заменить на cpp и ещё вот https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022#use-the-export-template-wizard

Если вы это читаете, то вам точно не следует пытаться добавить Мастер экспорта шаблонов вручную, т.к. он в любом случае сам по себе работать не будет. Согласно ответу Alex S2020 здесь: https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_other-winapps/как-в-visual-studio-community/996f400d-739f-4a1f-bc84-c532a4ba213e
есть лишь ограниченные типы проектов, которые могут предоставить вам пункт меню, вместе с полностью преднастроенным мастером.
Так например, чтобы создать свой первый базовый шаблон элемента, нужно:

Запустить Visual Studio выбрав "Создание проекта".
В окне поиска шаблонов введите "Windows Forms", согласно предложению Alex S2020 в ответе выше.
Вы можете выбрать один из 3 проектов: "Приложение Windows Forms (Майкрософт)", "Приложение Windows Forms (.NET Framework)", "Классическое приложение Windows". Лично я пробовал последний.
Добавьте файл в проект, который вы хотите использовать как шаблон элемента.
Мастер шаблонов уже заведомо заранее в одном из выбранных проектов преднастроен. Всё что вам нужно пройти по шагам здесь и/или здесь, что в целом одно и тоже.

Если вы хотите создать и использовать шаблон в проекте из категории "Общее", то вероятно вы должны собрать свой собственный мастер, согласно инструкции здесь:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022#create-a-custom-template-wizard
Шаблон единовременно будет работать, лишь в одной из поддерживаемых типов категорий проектов: "CSharp", "VisualBasic", "VC"(С++), "Web". Подробнее здесь: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/extensibility/projecttype-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2022


Если вы не видите пункт меню "Экспорт шаблона", его можно добавить, выбрав "Настроить инструменты>", а затем выберите "Команды", панель меню "Проект", нажмите кнопку "Добавить команду", а затем в разделе "Проект" выберите "Экспорт шаблона...".

Источник: Создание шаблонов проектов

На самом деле, у меня уже есть некий прогресс и есть о чём рассказать. Пока что, я скажу лишь то, что принудительное добавление кнопки "Экспорт шаблона...", ни к чему не ведёт, она будет неактивна. Это связанно с тем, что наличие и работа самого мастера шаблонов, напрямую зависит от типа выбранного вами проекта, во время создания. Так например, у общих проектов, нету своего собственного мастера. Звучит как полный бред, но этот бред писал не я. Поэтому оно вот так.

Статья - "Добавление тегов к шаблонам проектов", которую вы скинули, ключ к решению ещё одной возникшей у меня проблемы. Завтра я напишу о том, что у меня получилось.

Экспорт действует на файл который у вас в проекте, а не на файл шаблона.

Я добавил свой собственный ответ, касательно того, что мне удалось выяснить. Кроме того, он фактически отвечает на поставленный вопрос, кому-нибудь кто ищет, будет полезно.
